# Using i18next translations without having the "key" as strings

Tags: i18next

I'm running into a strange compatibility issue where I cannot use strings as the key of my JSON. For example, if the below JSON is my translation file,

```
{
    "modules" : {
        "localization": {
          "modal" : "Modal localized (en-US)"
          }
    }
}
```

The system can only accept it without keys being strings, i.e. like :

```
{
    modules : {
        localization: {
          modal : "Modal localized (en-US)"
          }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to conigure i18next to achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean with "The system can only accept it without keys being strings". Without keys being strings, the file isn't valid JSON so i18next can't parse it :)

Comment: Well.. what I meant was, instead of passing a JSON string, is it possible to configure i18next to use a Javascript object directly.

Comment: Well, you can parse your object to JSON using `JSON.stringify(<your object>);` and then pass it to i18next :) But this requires that your've got an object and not only a string.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it, but does i18next provide an option to do this? As part of the options, I can only set "resGetPath" to specify the path to the JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

From http://i18next.com/pages/doc_init.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="i18next-1.7.4.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 data-i18n='key'>My First Heading</h1>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var resources = {
            dev: { translation: { key: 'value' } },
            en: { translation: { key: 'value' } },            
            'en-US': { translation: { key: 'value' } }
        };

        i18n.init({ 
            resStore: resources,
            lng: 'en-US'
        }, function(t) {
            $("h1").i18n();
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

You could load the object into resources some other way if that works better for you, this is just a simple demo. I couldn't find any way around having 'en-US' as a string - it complains about the '-' if it doesn't have quotes around it. This prevents it loading external resources though so I think you'd have to handle loading the resources from somewhere yourself.